# Can't get string comparison right

Tags: java

I need help with my code below, I cant get the string comparison right with regards to the **deleteNode** method.
I searched StackOverflow and [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) was helpful, especially with **Objects.equals**.

However, running the method falls through all if statements, and the item *never* gets deleted. PS, excuse my English, not native speaker.

My code:

```
public void deleteNode(String clientAddr) {
    boolean isFound = false;
    for (ClientNode client : srv.connections) {
        if (Objects.equals(client.getIpAddr(), clientAddr)) {
            isFound = true;
            srv.connections.remove(clientAddr);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isFound) {
        System.out.println("Provided address is not found!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Above is called via:

```
starNetwork.deleteNode("10.10.10.3");
```

If I for instance run the following:

```
public void deleteNode(String clientAddr) {
    for (ClientNode client : srv.connections) {
        System.out.println(Objects.equals(client.getIpAddr(), clientAddr));
    }
}
```

it outputs:

```
false
true
false
```

I don't understand

Comment: Please remove all irrelevant code and show a minimized, runnable example.

Comment: And in `deleteNode`, you're ending the program if the first client isn't the node to delete. You never check the rest of the clients.

Comment: I want to delete 10.10.10.3 from the ArrayList. Using simple tests, I can see that Objects.equals(client.getIPAddr, clientAddr) does return true for 10.10.10.3 but I cannot make it so that it deletes.

Comment: Why are you exiting? I doubt that's what you want to happen.

Comment: Is the exit not called only when matching that **if** clause?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I have removed the exit code, even tried what have been suggested below but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You check just the first element and exit the program if its not found. 
Instead try looping for the rest of the elements.

Also, you can't use remove() in a list of Object (of type ClientNode) and pass a String.
This means you're trying to compare a ClientNode Object with a String, which is not possible. So List is not removing any elements.

Recommend to use Iterators in such scenarios.

Change:

```
for (ClientNode client : srv.connections) {
 if (Objects.equals(client.getIpAddr(), clientAddr)) {
            srv.connections.remove(clientAddr);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Provided address is not found!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

To Something like:

```
boolean isFound = false;
for (Iterator<ClientNode> iterator = srv.connections.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    ClientNode client = iterator.next();
    if (Objects.equals(client.getIpAddr(), clientAddr)) {
        isFound = true;
        iterator.remove();
        break;
    }
}
if(!isFound) {
    System.out.println("Provided address is not found!");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

If you don't want to use a flag, then on first if condition write a return;
outside the loop blindly write a `System.out.println("Provided address is not 
found!");`

Comment: Hi @Bandi thanks for answering. I tried your answer, not woring for me. Output of display after running deleteNode() is still showing 3 clients.

Comment: @giovanni_m There was one more error, you were trying to perform a removal of types which don't match. I've modified the answer to make it work.

Comment: Ah, it works! So all I needed was a way to iterate over the items within the ArrayList? Thanks @Bandi

Answer (score 0):

Question has been answered with help from user Bandi Kishore below.
My deleteNode() method was not dealing with the right types, and was fixed with the help of an iterator.